# How can find data of any site for using CURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I created a program in php using CURL,  in which i can take data of any site and can display it in the browser. Another part of the program is that the data can be saved in the file using file handling and after saving this data, I can find all the http links within the body tag of the saved file. My code is showing all the sites in the browser which I took, but I can not find the http links and some unnecessary code is also occurring like this image, though I don't want it to come.

Kindly help me out this problem.

https://www.screencast.com/t/Nwaz93oU

PHP Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php
        function get_all_links(){
            $html = file_get_contents('http://www.ucertify.com');
            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            @$dom->loadHTML($html);
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
            $hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");
            for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
                $href = $hrefs->item($i);
                $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
                echo $url.'<br />';
            }
        }
        function get_site_data($uc_url){
            $get_uc = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($get_uc,CURLOPT_URL,$uc_url);
            curl_setopt($get_uc,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            $output=curl_exec($get_uc);
            curl_close($get_uc);
            $fp=fopen("mohit.txt","w");
            fputs($fp,$output);
            return $output;
        }
    ?>
    <body>
        <div>
            <?php
            $site_content = get_site_data("http://www.ucertify.com");
            echo $site_content;
            ?>
            </div>
            <div >
            <?php
            echo get_all_links("http://www.ucertify.com");
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is line 8 of the code? Showing us the whole script doesn't help minimize the problem.

Comment: Replace `&$matches` with `$matches`

Answer (score 0):

See the code below i also include comment on every updates.

on Line 5 Specify the $url Variable Value.
on Line 11 Remove & by (reference) from $matches. [Refer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) about perg_mach_all

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php

// You have to Set $Url Variable;
$url='http://www.society6.com';

$var = fread_url($url);

// Remove The & or by reference on $matches variable
preg_match_all ("/a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+". "(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>"."([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/", $var, $matches);

$matches = $matches[1];
$list = array();

foreach($matches as $var)
{
    print($var."<br>");
}

function fread_url($url,$ref="http://www.society6.com")
{
    if(function_exists("curl_init")){
        $ch = curl_init();
        $user_agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; ".
            "Windows NT 5.0)";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref );
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'curl.txt');
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    else{
        $hfile = fopen($url,"r");
        if($hfile){
            while(!feof($hfile)){
                $html.=fgets($hfile,1024);
            }
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

?>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: kindly see above edit. I can change my previous code or problem.